# Grab Largest Index From Grep Output In Pattern

Tags: bash, awk, grep

My coworker had an interesting problem today with `grep`. 
She is making a bash script that it seems to be pulling a webpage using `curl` from there and using `grep` to pull the anchors.

Her example output is coming out as:

```
    file-1    
    file-10
    file-2 
    file-20
    file-3
    file-4
```

this is expected as `grep` sorts by seeing that first numeric and putting them in its "order".

She ended up making a for-loop to grab the latest from the output. But it got me curious.

In the above example how will I obtain the `file-20` *in one line command*?

. I've tried `sort` and `awk`. Couldn't get working however :/

Comment: Why would grep be sorting? The output should be in the order grep found the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- Use numeric sort: `-n` flag for `sort`
- Sort by the numeric column: use `-t` to specify column separator, and `-k` to specify column
- Get the last line with `tail -n1`

Like this:

```
sort -n -t- -k2 input | tail -n1
```

Comment: simple and in one line. thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do this in a **single command**:

```
awk -F- '$2>max{max=$2; s=$0} END{print s}' file

file-20
```

We split each line by hyphen and examine 2nd field. We keep variable `max` as running value to keep the maximum value then we get higher value in `$2`. Every time we set `max` we also store full line in variable `s`. In the `END` section we just print variable `s`.

Comment: I like this one and love that you explained it thank you. Had to accept the other one just because it was simpler and she ended up liking to use that one. I have to get more oriented with `awk` first myself so thank you.

Comment: *simpler* is subjective term actually. `awk` is doing this in a single command vs two commands i.e. `sort + tail` and if input file is huge then `sort` will be considerably slower as well.

Comment: yeah your right. i meant simpler as in the first commands Ive learned were grep, sort and tail/head. awk is something im learning so the other ones were the easiest to use mentally i suppose haha. ill be sure to keep in mind that awk will be better for larger files!

Comment: Just to clarify difference is **not using sort** that will make this approach faster.

Comment: yeah that is understood

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` to sort by `-` separated second field numerically, and `head -1` to get the first one:

```
sort -t'-' -k2,2rn | head -1
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                        
file-1    
file-10
file-2 
file-20
file-3
file-4

% sort -t'-' -k2,2rn file.txt         
file-20
file-10
file-4
file-3
file-2 
file-1    

% sort -t'-' -k2,2rn file.txt | head -1
file-20
```

Comment: same one just used tail instead cause it was the first one seen thank you though!

Comment: @KyleCalica-St Note the difference is in the trailing part of the `-k` option, you can actually use `-n`(numeric), `-r`(reverse) etc operation for a specific portion, not on the whole line by tacking the relevant option with `-k`. Also if there were more trailing fields the other one would choke, you should always mention the starting and ending fields while using `-k`.