# bash output lines sorted by descending number

Tags: bash

Data looks like:

```
Web Application Attack: 1361698
Network Trojan was detected: 3272
Potentially Bad Traffic: 0
Misc activity: 0
Detection of Network Scan: 0
```

I'm looking for a command that will sort the lines by number, nothing I've tried has been working.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sort -n -r -t':' -k2,2 <data_file>
```

Explanation:

```
-n: Numeric sort
-r: Reverse (descending)
-t: Changes field separator to ':' character
-k: Sort key starts on field 2 and ends on field 2
```

Comment: awesome, I was just reading the second answer from this question. Which has the same solution, set up columns, set : as my delimiter then sort by k2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420034/grab-largest-index-from-grep-output-in-pattern