# How to sort lines based on first column ONLY?

Tags: sorting

Given input.txt :

```
12 pas
24 chinois
3 22
67 Il
32 Mais
4 héritier
155 vers
56 troupes
5 L
2 83
97 an
```

My sorting command :

```
sort -nr ./input.txt > ./out.txt
```

I get :

```
3 22
2 83
155 vers
97 an
67 Il
56 troupes
32 Mais
24 chinois
12 pas
5 L
4 héritier
```

**How to returns ?:**

```
155 vers
97 an
67 Il
56 troupes
32 Mais
24 chinois
12 pas
5 L
4 héritier
3 22
2 83
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-t` and `-k` such :

```
sort -n -r -t':' -k1,1 input.txt > out.txt
```

It returns :

```
155 vers
97 an
67 Il
56 troupes
32 Mais
24 chinois
12 pas
5 L
4 héritier
3 22
2 83
```

Explanation:

```
-n: Numeric sort
-r: Reverse (descending)
-t: Changes field separator to ':' character
-k: Sort key starts on field 2 and ends on field 2
```

Thanks to [bash output lines sorted by descending number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238854/1974961).